# React js - How to restore filters when clicking browser back button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm developing a **React js** app with some components, two of them are : **ItemList** and **ItemDetails**.

- **ItemList** renders a list of predefined items, which can be filtered by their name.
- When you click on an item in the list , you will be redirected to another page containing **ItemDetails** component and it shows you some details about the item.

when you use the back button on the details page , you will go back to the list page, but the filter will be gone.
What can i do to restore the filter?

I know a way of doing so is by using **React Context** but i don't know when i should empty the context.I want the filter to be restored if only if the browser back button was used to redirect to **ItemList**.
Is there a generic way to do so?

Comment: Persist you state and load from localStorage in constructor

Comment: Why is ItemList losing its state in the first place? If it gets unmounted when you navigate, consider storing the filter state further up the tree.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz then the filter will always be filled once it has been set, i don't want that to happen

Comment: @ChrisG what can i do not to let it get unmounted?

Comment: You'd have to put it in a `<Route>` that matches both its own path and all details paths, then set it to `display: none` if it's a details path. Not sure that's worth the trouble though, just move the filter state up to the main App.

Comment: @ChrisG the problem is that if i move to up to the main app, it will be filled even if i come to the list page from other pages , i want it to be set only when i press back button from details page